# I use @Resource, @Bean to inject bean, but sometimes the wrong bean gets injected

Tags: resources, javabeans, code-injection, autowired, inject

I use @Resource, @Bean to inject bean, But sometimes wrong bean injection. Why this?

```
-------- throw Exception

    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.B cannot be cast to com.test.A at 
    com.test.ModelA.handle(ModelA.java:35) at 
    com.test.ModelA.handle(ModelA.java:35) at 
    com.test.AbstractModel.execute(AbstractRule.java:12) at 
    com.test.AbstractModel.execute(AbstractRule.java:9) at 
    com.test.modelChain.execute(modelChain.java:35) at 
    com.test.BManager.process(BManager.java:66) at 
    com.test.BManager.process(BManager.java:31) at 
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor121.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at 
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at 
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) at 
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) at 
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) at 
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) at 
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) at 
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) at 
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at 
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) at 
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.process(Unknown Source) at 


-----AConfig.class--------------------------------------------------

    @Configuration
    public class AConfig<T>{

        @Autowired
        private Model<T> modelA;

        @Autowired
        private Model<T> modelB;

        @Bean
        public List<Model<T>> getAModelList(){
            List<Model<T>> lists = new ArrayList<Model<T>>();
            lists.add(modelA);
            return lists;
        }

        @Bean
        public List<Model<T>> getBModelList(){
            List<Model<T>> lists = new ArrayList<Model<T>>();
            lists.add(modelB);
            return lists;
        }
    }

-----AManager.class--------------------------------------------

    @Component
    public class AManager implements Manager<AA>{

        @Autowired
        private ModelChain<AA> modelChain;

        @Resource(name="getAModelList")
        private List<Model<AA>> aModelList;

        public void process(){
            modelChain.setModelList(aModelList);

            // process Logic to use aModelList
        }
    }

-----BManager.class--------------------------------------------------

    @Component
    public class BManager implements Manager<BB>{

        @Autowired
        private ModelChain<BB> modelChain;

        @Resource(name="getBModelList")
        private List<Model<BB>> bModelList;

        public void process(){
            modelChain.setModelList(bModelList);

            // process Logic to use bModelList
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does this means? 'But sometimes wrong bean injection'. Can you explain yourself better?

Comment: Wrapped the whole thing in code blocks. Edited title to a little better grammar.

Comment: @zed Sorry This mean is 'But sometimes Autowired injected wrong bean'

Comment: And I think, name field in Resource annotation is same with Qualifier annotation. is it right?